# What is the kotlin equivlant to Java annotation field with bounded wildcard type?

Tags: generics, annotations, kotlin

Say I have an annotation in Java like this:

```
public @interface Foo {
    Class<? extends Bar> value();
}

public interface Bar {}
```

How should I translate `Foo` into kotlin? Is it true that I could only switch back to Java in such situation?

Comment: I guess you can just give the type parameter a name: `fun <T : Bar> value(): Class<T>`.

Comment: @marstran Please notice this is an **annotation** and kotlin annotations even can't have a class body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin annotations cannot have method-definitions. They can, however, have constructor parameters. I think this works like you want it to:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

interface Bar
class Foo : Bar

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class Test(val value: KClass<out Bar>)

@Test(Foo::class)
fun testAnnotation() {
    println("Test")
}
```

Notice the **out** modifier on the `KClass` type parameter. It makes the type parameter *covariant*, meaning it can be of type `Bar` or any type that implements `Bar`.

Comment: I actually confused with scala, I tried both postfixing and prefixing the type with a plus(`+`), and, well, of course it yields some weird compliant error.